# A proof question using the gamma function and its properties.

Tags: derivatives, gamma-function

I encountered a proof question as the following shows:

[image: question pic]

I can solve the first sub-question by using divisional integration method for $\Gamma(x+1)$.

But I got problems on the second sub-question. Even though I could write down and somewhat simplify the $J_{m-1}(x)$ and $J_{m+1}(x)$, if I am doing right, they are:
$$J_{m-1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!\Gamma(m+n)}\left(\frac x2\right)^{m-1+2n}\;\;\;\;(1)$$
$$J_{m+1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!\Gamma(m+n+2)}\left(\frac x2\right)^{m+1+2n}\;\;\;\;(2)$$
I can also get the derivation of $J_{m}(x)$:
$$2\frac{J_m(x)}{dx}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!\Gamma(m+n+1)}\left(\frac x2\right)^{m-1+2n}(m+2n)\;\;\;\;(3)$$
But I got confused just from the start. As you can see, although in (1) and (3) the power of x is the same, in (2) and (3) they have a $\left(\frac x2\right)^2$ difference. As x is a variable, how can $(1)-(2)=(3)$? So I totally have no ideas.

I do not know whether my thoughts are somewhere wrong or maybe the question did not clarify clearly somewhere. But could you give me some hints or comments on this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write 
$$J_{m+1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!\Gamma(m+n+2)}\left(\frac x2\right)^{m+1+2n}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!\Gamma(m+n+1)}\left(\frac x2\right)^{m-1+2n}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n(-1)^{n-1}}{n!\Gamma(m+n+1)}\left(\frac x2\right)^{m-1+2n}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n(-1)^{n-1}}{n!\Gamma(m+n+1)}\left(\frac x2\right)^{m-1+2n}$$
and notice that
$$\frac1{\Gamma(m+n)}+\frac n{\Gamma(m+n+1)}=\frac{m+2n}{\Gamma(m+n+1)}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your splendid answer! I understand your main thinking, but I am still not so clear on some points of your answer. May I ask it? In the first step: $J_{m+1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!\Gamma(m+n+2)}\left(\frac x2\right)^{m+1+2n}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!\Gamma(m+n+1)}\left(\frac x2\right)^{m-1+2n}$ , are you using n-1 to replace n? If so, in the final transformation step. how do you change $n=1$ to $n=0$ with totally unchanging all the rest part?

Comment: I guess may be adding a $n=0$ element to the original formula would not change anything, as the adding element's value is 0?

Comment: @PeterNova Yes, that's exactly right. In the first step you replace $n$ with $n-1$, and in the last step you note that the contribution of the term $n=0$ is zero.